# download the following model: distill-bert-base-spanish-wwm-cased-finetuned-spa-squad2-es

Tags: bert-language-model, transformer-model

I have two PCs: one of them has an internet connection and the other PC does not have an internet connection, I need to download the following model: `distill-bert-base-spanish-wwm-cased-finetuned-spa-squad2-es`, but not I find the link.

I do not have and i cannot install python on the pc with internet access, but I can use wget.

Where i can download the following model: `distill-bert-base-spanish-wwm-cased-finetuned-spa-squad2-es`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get and use the model directly from Transformers library at this [link](https://huggingface.co/mrm8488/distill-bert-base-spanish-wwm-cased-finetuned-spa-squad2-es).

You can also copy the example code from the same page and include it in your project using your pc with internet.